# Retrieve argument details defined in private function/procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

On similar line what Dba_argument do it has all the details of public function/procedure define in package.

Can somebody please help me how can I retrieve argument details of private function/procedure.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please check the answer in the linked thread. If it doesn't answer your question please explain what additional information you need. Please do not ask the same question for a third time.

Comment: But it doesn't give information of arguments like we get in dba_argument (argument_name, mode,data type etc). I need private function/procedure argument detials

Comment: PL/SCOPE gives us some of the information we get from  USER_PROCEDURES or USER_ARGUMENTS for public procedures but not all of it. Unfortunately Oracle provides nothing better right now.